# Switching Math to %Reported from just a count of Present

Tags: xslt

**Screenshot of tool**
[image: 1]

I have the following code that was written by another developer.  I have taken it as far as I can since I am not versed in XSLT.

Currently the math is set to just do a percentage of just those that have marked themselves P (Present).  I want the percentage to count everything but NR (not reported), or just do a math equation where it counts the NR percentage and subtracts it from 100% - either way will work.

Woolf CTR Sonia E
4:47 PM (21 minutes ago)
to me

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
<xsl:param name="dvt_apos">&apos;</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="dvt_groupfield" />
<xsl:param name="ListName">Morning Report</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="Day" />
<xsl:param name="Monday">=(2-WEEKDAY(Today)+(Today))</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
                                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
                                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)" />
                                        <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
                                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr valign="top">
                        <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
            </xsl:if>
            <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="" style="width: 129px">Name</th>
            <xsl:call-template name="table_header_query">
                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                                                        </xsl:call-template></tr>
                                                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="1" />
                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                                                        </xsl:call-template>
    
                                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.footer">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                        </table>
                        </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
                                        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
                                        <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
                                        <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
                                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_Rows"><root>
                                                        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                                                                        <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow)"><xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:if>
                                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </root></xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                                                        <xsl:variable name="NewGroup_0">
                                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                                                        <xsl:when test="not ($dvt_groupfield)"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:NameChanged(string(@PdM), 0)" /></xsl:when>
                                                                                        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                                                        <xsl:when test="0" />
                                                                        <xsl:when test="not($dvt_groupfield) and (not($NewGroup_0='') and position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow or ($FirstRow = position()))">
                                                                                        <xsl:variable name="groupheader0">
                                                                                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                                                                                                        <xsl:when test="not (@PdM) and (@PdM) != false()"><xsl:value-of select="' '" /></xsl:when>
                                                                                                                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="@PdM" /></xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                                        <xsl:variable name="groupfooter0">
                                                                                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                                                                                                        <xsl:when test="$NewGroup_0=''"><xsl:value-of select="@PdM" /></xsl:when>
                                                                                                                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$NewGroup_0" /></xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                                        <xsl:if test="not ((position()=1) or (position()=$FirstRow))">
                                                                                                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.groupfooter0">
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">Org</xsl:with-param>
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">PdM</xsl:with-param>
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="$groupfooter0" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype" select="''" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="nodeset" select="msxsl:node-set($dvt_Rows)/root//Row[((@PdM)=$groupfooter0 or ((not(@PdM) or @PdM='') and $groupfooter0=' '))]" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="groupid" select="'0'" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="displaystyle" select="'auto'" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="showfooter" select="true()" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="showfootercolumn" select="false()" />
                                                                                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                                                                        </xsl:if>
                                                                                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.groupheader0">
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">Org</xsl:with-param>
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">PdM</xsl:with-param>
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="$groupheader0" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype" select="''" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="nodeset" select="msxsl:node-set($dvt_Rows)/root//Row[((@PdM)=$groupheader0 or ((not(@PdM) or @PdM='') and $groupheader0=' '))]" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="groupid" select="'0'" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="displaystyle" select="'auto'" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="imagesrc" select="'/_layouts/images/plus.gif'" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="alttext" select="'expand'" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="altname" select="'collapse'" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="hidedetail" select="false()" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="showheader" select="true()" />
                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="showheadercolumn" select="false()" />
                                                                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        <xsl:variable name="BreakOut">
                                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                                                        <xsl:when test="not($dvt_groupfield) and position()=$LastRow+1"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:NameChanged('', -1)" /></xsl:when>
                                                                                        <xsl:otherwise>BreakOut</xsl:otherwise>
                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_KeepItemsTogether" select="false()" />
                                                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_HideGroupDetail" select="false()" />
                                                        <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow) or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether">
                                                                        <xsl:if test="not($dvt_HideGroupDetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                                                                                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
                                                                        </xsl:if>
                                                        </xsl:if>
                                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                                                        <xsl:when test="0" />
                                                                        <xsl:when test="($NewGroup_0 or true()) and not($dvt_groupfield)">
                                                                                        <xsl:variable name="groupfooter0">
                                                                                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                                                                                                        <xsl:when test="position() = count($Rows) and ($LastRow &gt;= position() or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether) or not($NewGroup_0) or $NewGroup_0=''"><xsl:value-of select="@PdM" /></xsl:when>
                                                                                                                         <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$NewGroup_0" /></xsl:otherwise>
                                                                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                                                        <xsl:if test="(position() = count($Rows) and ($LastRow=position() or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether)) or (not($dvt_KeepItemsTogether)  and position() &gt; $LastRow and not($BreakOut='BreakOut')) or (not($dvt_KeepItemsTogether) and position() = $LastRow+1) or (position()=last() and $LastRow &gt; last())">
                                                                                                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.groupfooter0">
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">Org</xsl:with-param>
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">PdM</xsl:with-param>
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="$groupfooter0" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype" select="''" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="nodeset" select="msxsl:node-set($dvt_Rows)/root//Row[((@PdM)=$groupfooter0 or ((not(@PdM) or @PdM='') and $groupfooter0=' '))]" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="groupid" select="'0'" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="displaystyle" select="'auto'" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="showfooter" select="true()" />
                                                                                                                        <xsl:with-param name="showfootercolumn" select="false()" />
                                                                                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                                                                        </xsl:if>
                                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                    
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
                                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_GroupStyle" select="'none'" />
                                        <tr style="display:{$dvt_GroupStyle}">
                                                        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
                                                                        <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
                                                        <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
            <td class="ms-vb" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="monLoc" select="@Mon_x005F_x0020_Location"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tuesLoc" select="@Tues_x005F_x0020_Location"/>
        <xsl:variable name="wedLoc" select="@Wed_x005F_x0020_Location"/>
        <xsl:variable name="thursLoc" select="@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Location"/>
        <xsl:variable name="friLoc" select="@Fri_x005F_x0020_Location"/>
        <xsl:variable name="listLocation" select="string-length(substring-before(@FileRef, 'sites'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="locationStripped">
            <xsl:call-template name="SubstringBeforeLast">
                <xsl:with-param name="String" select="@FileRef"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Char" select="'/'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="editURL" select="concat('/', substring($locationStripped, $listLocation+1), '/EditForm.aspx?ID=', @ID)"/>           
        <td class="ms-vb">
            <a href="{$editURL}"
                onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;"
                target="_self">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@UserName, ';#')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </a>
            
        </td><td class="ms-vb" title="{$monLoc}"><xsl:call-template name="color_reported">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@Mon_x005F_x0020_Status" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:value-of select="@Mon_x005F_x0020_Status" /></td><td class="ms-vb" title="{$tuesLoc}"><xsl:call-template name="color_reported">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@Tues_x005F_x0020_Status" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Tues_x005F_x0020_Status" /></td><td class="ms-vb" title="{$wedLoc}"><xsl:call-template name="color_reported">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@Wed_x005F_x0020_Status" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Wed_x005F_x0020_Status" /></td><td class="ms-vb" title="{$thursLoc}"><xsl:call-template name="color_reported">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Status" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Status" /></td><td class="ms-vb" title="{$friLoc}"><xsl:call-template name="color_reported">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="status"><xsl:value-of select="@Fri_x005F_x0020_Status" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Fri_x005F_x0020_Status" /></td>
                            </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_1.groupheader0">
                                        <xsl:param name="fieldtitle" />
                                        <xsl:param name="fieldname" />
                                        <xsl:param name="fieldvalue" />
                                        <xsl:param name="fieldtype" />
                                        <xsl:param name="nodeset" />
                                        <xsl:param name="groupid" />
                                        <xsl:param name="displaystyle" />
                                        <xsl:param name="imagesrc" />
                                        <xsl:param name="alttext" />
                                        <xsl:param name="altname" />
                                        <xsl:param name="hidedetail" />
                                        <xsl:param name="showheader" />
                                        <xsl:param name="showheadercolumn" />
                                        <xsl:if test="$showheader" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
        <tr id="group{$groupid}" style="display:{$displaystyle}">
            <td class="ms-gb" style="background:#cccccc;" colspan="8">
                <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='0' or $groupid='9'">
                                                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='1'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='2'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='3'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='4'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='5'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='6'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:if test="not($hidedetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                    <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpGroupBy(this);return false;">
                        <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" name="{$altname}" /></a>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                
                <xsl:if test="$fieldvalue!='PMO'">
                <b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$fieldtitle" />
                </b>
                <xsl:if test="$fieldtitle">: </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$fieldtype='url'">
                        <a href="{$fieldvalue}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue" />
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$fieldtype='user'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                        </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.groupfooter0">
                <xsl:param name="fieldtitle" />
                <xsl:param name="fieldname" />
                <xsl:param name="fieldvalue" />
                <xsl:param name="fieldtype" />
                <xsl:param name="nodeset" />
                <xsl:param name="groupid" />
                <xsl:param name="displaystyle" />
                <xsl:param name="showfooter" />
                <xsl:param name="showfootercolumn" />
                <xsl:if test="$showfooter" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
        <tr id="group{$groupid}" style="display:{$displaystyle}">
            <td class="ms-gb" style="background:#cccccc;" colspan="1" align="right">
                <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='0' or $groupid='9'"></xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='1'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$groupid='2'">
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <b><u>%Reported</u>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-gb">
                <xsl:call-template name="color_present">
                    <xsl:with-param name="present"><xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset[@Mon_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset)" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>

                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count($nodeset[@Mon_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset), '0%')" /></td>
            <td class="ms-gb">
            <xsl:call-template name="color_present">
                    <xsl:with-param name="present"><xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset[@Tues_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset)" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count($nodeset[@Tues_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset), '0%')" /></td>
            <td class="ms-gb">
            <xsl:call-template name="color_present">
                    <xsl:with-param name="present"><xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset[@Wed_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset)" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count($nodeset[@Wed_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset), '0%')" /></td>
            <td class="ms-gb">
            <xsl:call-template name="color_present">
                    <xsl:with-param name="present"><xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset[@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset)" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count($nodeset[@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset), '0%')" /></td>
            <td class="ms-gb">
            <xsl:call-template name="color_present">
                    <xsl:with-param name="present"><xsl:value-of select="count($nodeset[@Fri_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset)" /></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count($nodeset[@Fri_x005F_x0020_Status!='NR']) div count($nodeset), '0%')" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.footer">
                <xsl:param name="Rows" />
        
        <tr >
            <td class="ms-vh" style="color:black; width: 129px;" align="right"><b><u>Org Totals</u></b></td>
            <td class="ms-vh" colspan="8"></td>
        </tr>
        
        <xsl:variable name="presMon" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Mon_x005F_x0020_Status='P'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="presTues" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Tues_x005F_x0020_Status='P'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="presWed" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Wed_x005F_x0020_Status='P'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="presThurs" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Status='P'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="presFri" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Fri_x005F_x0020_Status='P'])" />

        <tr >
            <td class="ms-vb" align="right" style="width: 129px"><u>O/H</u></td>
            <td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="$presMon" /></td>
            <td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="$presTues" /></td>
            <td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="$presWed" /></td>
            <td class="ms-vb" style="width: 13px"><xsl:value-of select="$presThurs" /></td>
            <td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="$presFri" /></td><td class="ms-vb" style="width: 26px">
            <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            </td></tr>
        
        <xsl:variable name="offMon" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Mon_x005F_x0020_Status='O'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="offTues" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Tues_x005F_x0020_Status='O'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="offWed" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Wed_x005F_x0020_Status='O'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="offThurs" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Thurs_x005F_x0020_Status='O'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="offFri" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Fri_x005F_x0020_Status='O'])" />
        <xsl:if test="($offMon + $offTues + $offWed + $offThurs + $offFri) != 0">
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example input, an executable XSLT and expected output - not snippets of code taken out of context. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want a screen shot of what the rendering looks like?